# A short way of cheking multiple blank text fields jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to check if there are blank input text fields in my < form >. Instead of doing this multiple times

```
$.trim($('#myMessage').val()) == '' || $.trim($('#myage').val()) == '' .//so on...
```

What is the best way to check multiple blank text fields?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use:

```
if($('input:text[value=""]').length);
```

Comment: Beautiful! But how does this refer to a specific < form > ?

Comment: You can do like if($('#form input:text[value=""]').length);

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$("form input[type=text]").filter(function () {
    return $.trim(this.value) != "";
}).length;
```

Note: You have to use any form id or class  instead of  form

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy check mail da

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code ,

```
// Validate form fields in Sign up form 
$(".signup-form").submit(function(){
    var isFormValid = true;
    $(".signup-form .required input:text").each(function(){ // Note the :text
        if ($.trim($(this).val()).length == 0){
            $(this).parent().addClass("highlight");
            isFormValid = false;
        } else {
            $(this).parent().removeClass("highlight");
        }
    });
    if (!isFormValid) alert("Please fill in all the required fields (highlighted in red)");
    return isFormValid;
});
```